# How to connect to my Microsoft mail using python to retrieve mail?

Tags: python, email, imap

I'm unable to connect to my email.
Some information about Microsoft IMAP sever name, host, encryption I got from this link https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/pop-imap-and-smtp-settings-for-outlook-com-d088b986-291d-42b8-9564-9c414e2aa040

Is there something wrong with my code?

This is my code

```
import imaplib
import pprint

imap_host = 'outlook.office365.com:993'
imap_user = 'myemail@hotmail.com'
imap_pass = 'password'


imap = imaplib.IMAP4(imap_host) # code dosen't execute past this line. I guess it has something to do with SSL or TSL

## login to server
imap.login(imap_user, imap_pass)

imap.select('Inbox')

tmp, data = imap.search(None, 'ALL')
for num in data[0].split():
    tmp, data = imap.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
    print('Message: {0}\n'.format(num))
    pprint.pprint(data[0][1])
    break
imap.close()
```

This is the error message I'm getting

```
File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Python project\email-server\getemail.py", line 9, in <module>
    imap = imaplib.IMAP4(imap_host)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\imaplib.py", line 202, in __init__
    self.open(host, port, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\imaplib.py", line 312, in open
    self.sock = self._create_socket(timeout)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\imaplib.py", line 302, in _create_socket
    return socket.create_connection(address)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\socket.py", line 824, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\socket.py", line 955, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

Comment: `outlook.office365.com:993` is not the hostname. Hostname is `outlook.office365.com` and `993` is the port. Try using them that way.

Comment: @zvone it did work after using hostname and port separately. Thank you!

Comment: You need IMAP4_SSL as well.